# shuffle two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

Sorry, I am beginner in java. I have defined two arrays. one of the types is string and the other is integer. now, i want to shuffle them.Assume id = {12, 45, 78, 23} and name = {"math", "physic", "art", "computer"}. for example after shuffling the arrays will become id = {78,45,23,12} and name = {"physic", "art", "math", "computer"}. i wrote the below code which does not work. how can i fix it?

```
public class RandomNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    long[] numbers = new long[4];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random id = new Random(4);
    String[] name = new String[4];

    for (int i=0; i<=numbers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextLong();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=numbers.length; i++)
    {
        int randomPosition = id.nextInt(4);
        long temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = randomPosition;
        numbers[randomPosition] = temp;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        name [i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)
    {
        int randomPosition = id.nextInt(4);
        String temp = name[i];
        name[i] = randomPosition;
        name [randomPosition] = temp;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + " ID = " + numbers[i] + " and name = " + name[i]);
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=numbers.length; i++)` - Why the `=`?

Comment: right, i eliminate it.

Comment: FYI: "does not work" is not a valid statement - what happens when you execute your code, what do you expect it to do, what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: when i have entered numbers, i could not enter the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
    int randomPosition = id.nextInt(4);
    long temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[randomPosition];
    numbers[randomPosition] = temp;
```

You have the 3rd line different.

```
numbers[i] = randomPosition;
```

The same applies to names.

You had a few other bugs too.

Here is your code fixed.
Compare it with yours.
You will see what was changed.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] numbers = new long[4];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random id = new Random(4);
        String[] name = new String[4];

        System.out.print("Enter the numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextLong();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = id.nextInt(4);
            long temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[randomPosition];
            numbers[randomPosition] = temp;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the names: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            name[i] = input.next();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = id.nextInt(4);
            String temp = name[i];
            name[i] = name[randomPosition];
            name[randomPosition] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " ID = " + numbers[i] + " and name = " + name[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could take those arrays and add them to the List and then use the shuffle methods from the Collections:

`Collections.shuffle(List myList);`

see the same answer for a different question on: 
[How can I make this into a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035176/how-can-i-make-this-into-a-loop)

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035176/how-can-i-make-this-into-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

As you do have a two value information, why not use a Map

```
    Map<Integer, String> toRandomize = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    toRandomize.put(1, "One");
    toRandomize.put(2, "Two");
    toRandomize.put(3, "Etc");

    Random r = new Random();

    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(toRandomize.keySet());
    while (!keys.isEmpty()) {
        Integer key = keys.remove(r.nextInt(keys.size()));
        String val = toRandomize.get(key);
        System.out.println("key=" + key + ", val=" + val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Collections to shuffle an array of primitive types is a bit of an overkill...

It is simple enough to implement the function yourself, using for example the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

import java.util.*;

class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int[] solutionArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11 };

    shuffleArray(solutionArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < solutionArray.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(solutionArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
  static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
Arrays.sort(numbers, randomComparator);
```

where randomComparator is an instance of Comparator who will randomly choose the order between 2 elements:

```
// assuming T is your array type:
int compare(T o1, T o2) {
  return (int)Math.signum(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
}
```

What does this do?
`Math.random() * 2 - 1` will generate a number between -1 and 1. The key is that it can generate a negative, positive number or zero.
The `Math.signum` translates it to -1, 0, 1.

That's all, enjoy!

Comment: I think a Comparator breaking the contract can be considered an ugly hack.

Comment: It's not an ugly hack, it is often used in Javascript world too. :) Also, the contract meaning should be your objective, not some evangelist opinion.

Comment: ```It's not an ugly hack, it is often used in Javascript world too``` ... well, you've proved my point :D Anyway I think breaking the contract of JDK classes should be done only in exceptional cases and commented properly. Consider someone else reading that code who don't know comparator interface, so he checks the javadoc and on the first line he reads ```A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects```. Quite a confusion. Your solution may work here, but if someone will want to reuse the "shuffling" comparator in different context will fail hard.

Comment: The Javadoc of this comparator will clearly state that it is used for random sorting if used somewhere in my code, of course. :)